# Is it possible to read the content of a txt file and display it using System.out.print();?

Tags: java

I would like to be able to display the content of a .txt file in my output terminal (Using the System.out.print() command).

I have already tried the fileInputStream /outputStream but I either didn't used it correctly or it didn't work out as I thought it would.

The goal would be to display the content in my file with the same line feed, etc...

Comment: Please add your current code to your question .

Comment: Checkout the great Mkyong article [Java – Read a text file line by line](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-text-file-line-by-line/).

Comment: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html

Comment: InputStream is great for reading bytes, but if you want to read text, a Reader is a better choice. Either wrap your stream in a `InputStreamReader` or use a `FileReader`

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers, I'm sorry for not adding my code to my question, I am not entirely familiar with this platform yet :).

Comment: Add it as best you can, and the community can help with formatting

Answer (score 0):

Just use the scanner (or reader) to read each line of the text file and then print it out as so.

```
    String path = "testFilePath.txt";
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path))) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It's better to use `scanner.nextLine()` inside `println()`, or the output would have every element of the contents, split at blank spaces, on a new line.

Comment: Good catch. Updated =).